# Adding values of one table into another with INSERT INTO ... SELECT

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I need to add value to table `sales(acnum,scriptname,shares_bought)` from `transac(acnum,scriptname,Quantity,Price)` using c# in visual studio 2008. I am using the code shown below, but it is not inserting value into sales database.

It is not showing any error or exception but its not updating `sales` table also.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        Con.Open();
        string insertsale = "INSERT INTO sales(acnum, scriptname, shares_bought) select acnum,scriptname,Quantity from transac";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertsale, Con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("error" + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you added the `DataTable` tag? That's a . NET in-memory collection.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I didnot get u

Comment: I think you need `Values` to be places `shares_bought) VALUES select`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava No Mohit.. i tried tht one also but it is still not working

Comment: Rewrite it to `int inserted=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and look at the value of `inserted`. Is it really 0? Does the table `transac` contain rows at all?

Comment: can u see what is the value of `insertsale`

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes there is data in transac table

Comment: @MohitShrivastava how to check the value of insertsale??

Comment: @Darkknight: and the value of `inserted` was 0?

Comment: @MohitShrivastava The value of `insertsale` is obviously the string the OP provided vcontaining the query itself. Nothing special on here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : how to check the value of it bro??

Comment: What this query returns: `select acnum,scriptname,Quantity from transac`?
Also, please double check your connection string.

Comment: connection string is alright!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: First execute this query directly on the database (`INSERT INTO sales(acnum, scriptname, shares_bought) select acnum,scriptname,Quantity from transac`). If it works (inserts data) then it must be the connection string.

Comment: @Darkknight: haven't i told you? `int inserted=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` Set a breakpoint at the next line and inspect the value of `inserted` in the debugger. If the breakpoint doesn't get hit you got an exception and you should set a breakpoint in the `Catch`. Maybe you don't see the exception on your page for whatever reasons.

Comment: @bpiec I have tried the query in SQL server management studio it has worked fine... the sales table has updated successfully

Comment: @TimSchmelter : no use sir, could not find any error here

Comment: @Darkknight: what is the value of `inserted`? Until you say that it's 0 we don't talk about anything else.

Comment: value of insertsale is INSERT INTO sales(acnum, scriptname, shares_bought) select acnum,scriptname,Quantity from transac"

Comment: @TimSchmelter now its working sir... thank you for all ur help

Comment: Thanks to all who tried to solve the problem

Comment: @Darkknight: what was the reason, what was your aolution? Maybe you can provide an answer that you can accept then. That would be helpful for future readers.

Comment: as u say @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had used PostUrl for the button click . . so i think it was redirecting to the nextpage without processing the code. Now its fixed .

Comment: Which means that you haven't seen the error that was raised? If so, what was the problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: I have seen Tim.. there was problem with connection string also, but code was perfect